# How to make this elif statement more efficient

Tags: python

```
future=random.randint(1,8)

if future == 1:
         answer = option1
elif future == 2:
         answer = option2
elif future == 3:
         answer = option3
elif future == 4:
         answer = option4
elif future == 5:
         answer = option5
elif future == 6:
         answer = option6
elif future == 7:
         answer = option7
else:
         answer = option8
```

I need this to be shortened/more efficient, any help would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not store the options in a list?

```
options = [option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8]
future = random.randint(0,7)
answer = options[future]
```

Comment: Thanks man, this worked as intended, and I can't believe I didn't get this sooner :P

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a dictionary:

```
import random
future=random.randint(1,8)

answer_dict = {1: option1, 2: option2, 3: option3, 4: option4, 5: option5, 6: option6 ,7: option7}
answer = answer_dict.get(future, option8)
```